# Error on passing data from controller to view of Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am facing a wired problem for more than 2 hours. I couldn't figured it out. I am trying to pass the variable `"errors"` from model to view but when I try to load the page it shows error saying `"undefined variable: errors"`. I am trying to build a "register" page for registering new users. 
Here is my controller for register

```
function register(){
    if($_POST){
        $config = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[3]|is_unique[users.username]'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[5]'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password2',
                'label' => 'Password Confirm',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[5]|matches[password]'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'user_type',
                'label' => 'User Type',
                'rules' => 'required'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email'
            )
        );
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
        }else{
            $data_array = array(
                'username' => $_POST['username'],
                'password' => sha1($_POST['password']),
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'user_type' => $_POST['user_type']
            );
            $this->load->model('user');
            $userid = $this->user->create_user($data_array);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $userid);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_type',$_POST['user_type']);
            redirect(base_url().'index.php/posts');
        }
    }
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('register_user');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

In above when there is a error in validation I set the error in $data['errors'] array. 
The view is given below

```
<h2>Register User</h2>
<?php if($errors): ?>
<div style="background:red;color:white;">
<?php echo $errors; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when I open the register page on browser, it shows the error saying `"Undefined variable: errors"`. Can anyone tell me where I have done wrong?

Comment: You need to pass an array to `$this->load->view` as the 2nd parameter.  CodeIgniter takes the keys from that array, and makes them variables in the view file.  Make sure `$errors` is set before trying to echo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any data to your views.  You can use the 2nd parameter to pass data to your views so rather than doing

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('register_user');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

You want to do

```
$aData['errors']
$this->load->view('header', $aData);
$this->load->view('register_user', $aData);
$this->load->view('footer', $aData);
```

Then when you are in your view you can do

```
<h2>Register User</h2>
<?php if($errors): ?>
    <div style="background:red;color:white;">
        <?php echo $errors; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Or you can just test if ( validation_errors() ) directly from the view